# Вернуть массив из функции

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Боюсь, что снова спрошу какую-то очевидную для всех вещь, которая для меня не очевидна: у меня есть функция, которая должна вернуть массив байт:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct tube
{
  BYTE var1;    
  size_t var2;         
  BYTE  var3;    
};
#pragma pack()

tube* rez;

BYTE *MyFunc(){
    const unint sz = 6;
    BYTE replaced_origin[sz];
    for(int i =0;i<sz;i++) replaced_origin[i]=i;
    return replaced_origin;
}

rez = (tube*)MyFunc();
```

Я знаю, это не совсем верный подход. Во-первых в C++ не приветствуется возвращаться указатель на массив, поскольку его длина на выходе будет неизвестна и, принимая риски, я готов это сделать,т.к. в моем случае длина неизменна. Во вторых, насколько я понимаю, то строка `BYTE replaced_origin[sz]` *выделила память под массив на **стеке**, а значит вне метода этот указатель станет **невалидным***?

Знаю, в C++ часто вместо массива используют vector для возврата из функции. Но мне кажется излишним создавать vector для 6-байтного массива, длина которого заведомо известна. Так же знаю, что можно воспользоваться new для выделения памяти в куче. Но память в куче выделяется медленнее, чем на стеке.

В общем, одним словом мне бы хотелось бы вернуть из функции массив путем копирования по значению, но - я новичек в с++ - никак не могу понять, как это правильно оформить

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам в самом деле **надо возвращать массив из 6 байт**? Возможно вместо этого лучше подойдет функция, которая **записывает эти 6 байт** по переданному ей адресу.

Comment: Тут в первую очередь возникает вопрос о том, что это за странные выкрутасы: `rez = (tube*)MyFunc();`. А уж возвращение массива из функции тут сбоку припеку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если знаете точный размер во время компиляции - используйте `std::array`, если не знаете - `strd::vector`. Накладных расходов в первом случае никаких, во втором - минимальные, а вот плюсов очень много - не надо беспокоиться о всех проблемах владения.

Беспокоиться о том, сколько времени занимает выделение памяти, и сколько - копирование, будет потом, когда профайлер ясно покажет, что ваш затык именно в этом (во что лично я не верю - добро бы выделяли/освобождали память в каком-то особо быстром цикле, но вот так, разово?

Если вы любитель эффективности :) - создавайте массив *вне функции*, и передавайте внутрь указатель на него. Это быстрее и надежнее.

И еще - меня очень смущает, что вы работаете со структурой как с массивом байтов. Так ли уж это необходимо? Чем вот это хуже?

```
tube rez;

void MyFunc(tube * t)
{
    t->var1 = 0;
    t->var2 = 0x04030201;
    t->var3 = 0x05;
}

MyFunc(&rez);
```

Или это?

```
tube rez;

void MyFunc(tube & t)
{
    t.var1 = 0;
    t.var2 = 0x04030201;
    t.var3 = 0x05;
}

MyFunc(rez);
```

Comment: Самое простое (если мы о С++) - написать конструктор, роль которого и выполняет, по сути, `MyFunc`.

Comment: >> смущает, что вы работаете со структурой как с массивом байтов << - мне кажется это довольно удобным инструментом. К сожалению, я использую древний компилятор, в нем еще нет поддержки C++11, а насколько я понял, std::array появился только с ним

Comment: @digital-mag - это может и удобный, но крайне опасный инструмент, неявно предполагающий что `sizeof(size_t) == 4 * sizeof(BYTE)`

Comment: @andy.37, ну в принципе, эту опасность можно обойти через препроцессорные директивы #ifdef, если задать #pragma для разных разрядностей ос?

Comment: @andy.37 Человек не спрашивает, как вернуть структуру, а как вернуть массив :)

Comment: @Harry Ну и где в Ваших примерах возврат из функции массива ;)

Answer (score 1):

Если мы говорим о С++, самое простое:

```
struct tube
{
  BYTE var1 = 0x00;
  size_t var2 = 0x04030201;
  BYTE var2 = 0x05;
}

tube MyFunc()
{
  return tube();
}
```

Собственно, в этом случае, ценность самой функции - нулевая.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам "*кажется излишним создавать vector для 6-байтного массива, длина которого заведомо известна*" и при этом не хочется создавать массив в динамической памяти, то есть еще один вариант. Объявите его как

```
static BYTE replaced_origin[sz];
```

и возвращайте его адрес на здоровье. Такой массив будет существовать все время выполнения программы. Вообще использование статических переменных без явной необходимости считается плохим стилем, но тем не менее это совершенно корректное решение.